# Safe way to get the current HttpSession in Spring 3+

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-mvc, servlets, jetty

In Spring 2+ I used to retrieve the javax.servlet.http.HttpSession via autowired constructor without any bean declaration:

```
@Service
class UserService @Autowired constructor(
        private val userRepository: UserRepository,
        private val httpSession: HttpSession,
) { }
```

In my application I use Jetty which apparently doesn't support servlet 6.0. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#jetty. I downgraded the jakarta servlet in dependency management to 5.0.0 for the whole application, but that didn't work:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

In spring 3.1.6 with jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession, that construct returns an error at the build process when tests kick off. I get the following error message:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:
Parameter 1 of constructor in api.core.user.UserService required a bean of type 'jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession' in your configuration.

What is the correct way to get my hands on that bean?

Comment: If you have proper dependency of jakarta, then try Invalidate cache in your IDE

Answer (score 0):

I think that the HttpSession bean is typically managed by the servlet container, so you need to declare it explicitly in your configuration using a configuration class.

```
@Configuration
public class HttpSessionConfig {

@Bean
@SessionScope
public HttpSession getHttpSession() {
    ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
    return attr.getRequest().getSession(true); // true creates a new session if one doesn't exist
}
}
```

Autowire the HttpSession in your service class:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

private final UserRepository userRepository;
private final HttpSession httpSession;

@Autowired
public UserService(UserRepository userRepository, HttpSession httpSession) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.httpSession = httpSession;
}
}
```

Now, Spring will automatically inject the HttpSession bean into your UserService class.

Comment: that doesn't help, the whole servlet context is missing.